# Was it ever clarified what will happen if Christine is killed?

Tags: plot-explanation, end-of-days

OK, this is probably not answerable, but I'm curious.

The movie End of Days (terrible movie, I realize, but it's a guilty pleasure movie of mine), there was a line said in the church, after Christine York (Robin Tunney) has taken refuge there with Father Kovak and others, when a cardinal and some of of his "lackeys" walk in with the intention of killing her.  (I know he's a cardinal cause he's called "your Eminence").

The priest, Father Kovak (played by Rod Steiger) says "But you can't prevent evil by doing evil.", which, of-course, the Cardinal and the people with him pay no attention to and say "there's no time, she had to die, yada yada (I'm paraphrasing).

Is it ever implied or suggested that bad things will happen on Earth if she's killed?  Or will bad things only happen if she is seduced and has a child with Gabriel Burn, aka, Satan?

Perhaps the movie wasn't thought out that carefully, but I'm curious if anyone knows more about this than I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The movie rendition doesn't explicitly state any unusual consequences for Christine's death. It's entirely possible that her death would be a clean resolution to the movie - presumably as long as she's killed in such a way which as to avoid her falling into Satan's hands during/post process.

That said, Kovak probably knows more than we do about these matters; since he implies it wouldn't work, either it's not possible to kill her without putting her in Satan's hands and speeding up her impregnation, or her death leads to a more serious catastrophe than her life + pregnancy would lead to.